# Android panResponder reports incorrect Animated.Value when useNativeDriver is on

Tags: android, react-native, animation

When use panResponder to animate an Animated.Value that has useNativeDriver set to true, the animated.Value reports wrong value sporadically. This issue is only reproducible on Android, not on iOS or web.

I am using react native 0.68.1 locally and 0.71 in snack expo

Created a demo snack to reproduce this issue: https://snack.expo.dev/@vividliu/d827f6.

The draggable box is attached to panelY Animated.Value, and animated to -300 in Y axis when mounts.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(panelY, {
        toValue: -300,
        duration: 400,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }).start()
  }, [])
```

After it mounts, dragging the box moves it in Y axis, and you can see in the log that the animated value has incorrect value sporadically.

// listener to listen for panelY value

```
  useEffect(() => {
    panelY.addListener(({value}) => {
        console.log(`panelY listener final value: ${value}. _offset=${panelY._offset}, _value=${panelY._value}`, );
    })
  }, [])
```

outputs:

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -277.1645812988281. _offset=-300, _value=22.835418701171875

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -577.1645812988281. _offset=-300, _value=-277.1645812988281

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -274.1921157836914. _offset=-300, _value=25.807884216308594

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
_** panelY listener final value: -574.1921157836914. _offset=-300, value=-274.1921157836914**

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -273.0788345336914. _offset=-300, _value=26.921165466308594

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -573.0788345336914. _offset=-300, _value=-273.0788345336914

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -271.55936431884766. _offset=-300, _value=28.440635681152344

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -571.5593643188477. _offset=-300, _value=-271.55936431884766

sdk_gphone_x86_arm:
panelY listener final value: -270.0352325439453. _offset=-300, _value=29.964767456054688

Notice there are some incorrect value in the middle of dragging sequence.
From what I can observe, the panelY._value is updated incorrectly. Instead of setting gesture.dy to panelY._value, panelY._value seems to be set to the overall value.

If useNativeDriver is set to false, the panelY value is updated correctly.

expect the Animated.Value is updated correctly when useNativeDriver is on